# exchange powershell : parsing an array boolean value

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

In my output, I get

@{ActiveSyncEnabled=False}

how do I parse this so that it just says "False"?

the output is coming from this line of code:

```
 $pda = get-casmailbox -Anr $user.displayname | select activesyncenabled
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have access to an exchange box right now, but the information should be there now for someone that does. Here is what worked:

$pda = get-casmailbox -Anr $user.displayname | select activesyncenabled
$pda.ActiveSyncEnabled | Write-Host

Comment: that didn't work..  the output is now "@{activesyncenabled.ActiveSyncEnabled=}"  thanks

Comment: When you say "output" how are you generating the output? Are you just doing Write-Host $pda?

Comment: I'm doing something similar ..   $pda | write-host

Comment: What if you go back to the way that you were populating $pda before then use this: $pda.ActiveSyncEnabled | Write-Host

Comment: hey that worked!  I didn't know you could do that till now.  thanks man

Answer (score 1):

To access the value directly:

(get-casmailbox -Anr $user.displayname).activesyncenabled

You can skip anr and use the identity member:

Get-CASMailbox $user.Identity

To get all activesyncenabled enabled mailboxes:

get-casmailbox -resultSize unlimited -filter {activesyncenabled -eq $true}